Charge transfer between connected conductors
My book says that "When one conductor is kept inside other conductor and connected, complete charge transfer takes place."

I know that their potential would be the same but why does complete charge transfer takes place? What is the reason and logic behind it?

Answer 1 is right.

The easiest explanation is the mutual electrostatic repulsion of the mobile charges (electrons) on the conductors. They redistribute to minimize their potential energy according to Coulomb's law. In a conducting (hollow) sphere, this leads to charge residing only on the outer surface of the sphere. On the inside there is no charge. Thus, if you introduce a charged metal object into a hollow piece of metal and contact the inside, all the charge will flow to the outer surface of the enclosing metal.
You can also consider it this way. As long as a charged metal object is inside a hollow metal without contacting the inner surface, according to Gauss's law, an electric charge of equal magnitude but opposite sign will be induced on the inner surface of the metal. Upon contact these opposite charges annihilate each other leaving the inner surface and the inner object uncharged.
It is interesting to note that this phenomenon can be used to mechanically transport charge into a hollow metal (sphere,etc.), which is used in the van de Graaff high voltage generator and in Faraday's cup.
One can also consider it in terms of electrical potential. Any metal object with a positive charge on the inside of a hollow conductor, which is at constant potential, is at a higher electrical potential than the outer conductor because work has to be done against the electrostatic repulsion to transfer a test charge from the outer to the inner conductor. Upon contact, the positive charge flows to the lower potential of the outer conductor. The converse happens with a negative charge on the inner conductor. Thus complete charge transfer occurs to the outer conductor.
